# Adding new value to existing Stream

Tags: java, java-8, wildcard

Is there is a good way to add a new value to existing `Stream`? All I can imagine is something like this:

```
public <T> Stream<T> addToStream(Stream<T> stream, T elem ) {
    List<T> result = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    result.add(elem);
    return result.stream();
}
```

But I'm looking for something more concise that I can use in lambda expression without verbosity.

Another question appeared when I tried to implement *PECS* principle:

```
public <T> Stream<? super T> addToStream(Stream<? super T> stream, T elem ) {
    List<? super T> result = stream.collect(Collectors.toList()); //error
    result.add(elem);
    return result.stream();
}
```

Seems like wildcard doesn't work with `Stream.collect` and I'm wondering why.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `List` returned from `collect(Collectors.toList())` supports `add`, you can use `Collectors.toCollection` instead to choose the type of list you get.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The question belies an incorrect assumption: that streams actually contain their data.  They do not; streams are not data structures, they are a means for specifying bulk operations across a variety of data sources.

There are combinators for combining two streams into one, such as `Stream.concat`, and factories for creating streams from a set of known elements (`Stream.of`) or from collections (`Collection.stream`).  So you can combine these if you want to produce a new stream that is the concatenation of the stream you have in hand, along with a new stream describing the new elements.

The problem in your PECS example is that you've got three occurrences of `? super T`, and you are assuming they describe the same type, but they do not.  Each occurrence of a wildcard corresponds to a unique capture, which isn't what you want; you need to give that type variable a name so the compiler knows that the type of the list and the type of the input stream are the same.  (Also, don't materialize a collection; that's expensive, and potentially non-terminating if the stream is not finite.  Just use concat.)  So the answer is: you just got the generics wrong.  Here's one way to do it:

```
public<T> Stream<T> appendToStream(Stream<? extends T> stream, T element) {
    return Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of(element));
}
```

You confused yourself with PECS because you were thinking about "inserting" into the stream, when in fact you're consuming from it.

Comment: The method shouldn't be named "appendToStream"?
Otherwise I think the parameters of the concat method should be switched.

Comment: `concat` method can use but not to much,from javadoc:Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 54):

How about

```
return Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of(elem));
```

this is assuming the original Stream is finite. If it's not, you can concat them in a reversed order.

Comment: Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even StackOverflowException.

Comment: If order doesn't matter and you flip the order of the arguments you no longer need to be "assuming the original Stream is finite." `Stream.of` is guaranteed to be finite, and the resulting stream will produce all desired elements, regardless of whether the original `stream` is finite or not

Answer (score 7):

The [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has corresponding `#prepend()` and `#append()` methods. Here's an example how they can be used:

```
StreamEx.of("second").prepend("first").append("third").forEach(System.out::println);
```

An output is as follows:

```
first
second
third
```

Comment: Nice! Albeit, another library.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using a flatMap as follows:

```
public <T> Stream<T> appendToStream(Stream<T> stream, T element) {
    return stream.flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e, element));
}
```

This operates on the original stream so it can be just another intermediate operation on the stream, eg:

```
    stream.flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e, element))
            .map(...)
            .filter(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: How many times you want to add an element? :D Ounce for stream or once per element in original stream?

Comment: given above @user482745 comment (for example), this NOT the best way (even if there even is a "best"...).

Answer (score -1):

use stream builder like this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.Builder<Integer> builder = Stream.builder();
    builder.add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4).add(5).add(6);
    Stream<Integer> newStream = builder.build();
    newStream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```